# Python linear fitting with multiple error bars

Tags: python, statistics, matplotlib, curve-fitting, linear-regression

I am fitting some data with a linear fit. I want to weight the error bars. Up to this point, I have been using bulldogs [fitting.py](http://bulldog2.redlands.edu/facultyfolder/deweerd/tutorials/fitting.txt). Their `linear_fit` makes weighted linear regressions very easy. Unfortunately, the data I'm working with has error in both the X and Y directions.

I was wondering how, both practically (in Python) and theoretically (in statistical terms), this would be done.

Comment: Theoretically, this is [Total least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) - called [Deming regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) in the 2-variables case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of choices:

1. [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.7.x/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) (for the [total least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares))
2. [`scipy.odr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.ODR.html#scipy.odr.ODR) (for [Deming regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression)).

*Both of these solutions will account for independent error in X and Y directions (the scld array in odr).*

Comment: how does leastsq take the errors in x and y direction.? I can't find the paramters.

Comment: is that xtol? Sorry I should really improve this answer to have an example.

Comment: i think xtol is just a small value to determine when to stop the algo. i suppose it only works with scipy.odr.

Comment: `scipy.optimize.leastsq` does ordinary least squares, not total least squares.  The second choice is correct. though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`scipy.optimize.fmin()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin) function ([see this example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.10.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html)) to minimize the merit function (which you have to define) that calculates the squared deviations in the x- and y-directions.

Comment: The above link to the example by Stefano Messina is broken.

Comment: @aging_gorrila Sorry, I don't know why, I fixed the link, now it brings to the scipy.optimize tutorial page.